# Apache POI: Partial Cell fonts

Tags: apache, excel, apache-poi

If I crack open MS Excel (I assume), or LibreOffice Calc (tested), I can type stuff into a cell, and change the font of parts of the text in a cell, such as doing, in one cell, :

**This text is bold** and *this text is italicized*

Again, let me reiterate, that this string could exist in the shown format in one cell.

Can this level of customization be achieved with Apache POI? Searching only seems to show how to apply a font to an entire cell.

Thanks

===UPDATE===

As suggested below, I ended up going with the HSSFRichTextString (as I'm working with HSSF). However, after applying fonts (I tried bold and underline), my text would remain unchanged. This is what I attempted. To put things in context, I am working on something sports-related, in which it is common to display a match up in the form "awayteam"@"hometeam", and depending on certain external conditions, I would like to make one or the other bold. My code looks something like this:

```
    String away = "foo";
    String home = "bar";
    String bolden = "foo"
    HSSFRichTextString val = new HSSFRichTextString(away+"@"+home);

    if(bolden.equals(home)) {
        val.applyFont(val.getString().indexOf("@") + 1, val.length(), Font.U_SINGLE);
    } else if(bolden.equals(away)) {
        val.applyFont(0, val.getString().indexOf("@"), Font.U_SINGLE);
    }
    gameHeaderRow.createCell(g + 1).setCellValue(val);
```

As you can see, this is a snippet of code from a more complicated function than is displayed, but the brunt of this is actual code. As you can see, I'm doing val.applyFont to part of a string, and then setting a cell value with the string. So I'm not entirely sure what I did wrong there. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

KFJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POI does support it, the class you're looking for is [RichTextString](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html). If your cell is a text one, you can get a RichTextString for it, then apply fonts to different parts of it to make different parts of the text look different.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I'm at work, and this is for a side project, so I'll try this tonight, and if it works, I'll Checkmark your answer :)

Comment: Wow. That took a lot longer to get around to than I expected. Sorry about that. Anyway, it didn't work out. No errors or anything, but the text remained unformatted. I'll edit my post here and show you what is going on.

Comment: If you apply that font to the whole cell (via a style), does it look like you expect? (That'd be a good way to check you've the right font)

Comment: And again...side projects keep taking a back seat. I kept poking at it and eventually it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You would be drained if working with SXSSFWorkbook, as it does not support such formatting.
Check it here.
http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/RichTextString-isn-t-working-for-SXSSFWorkbook-td5711695.html

Comment: I appreciate the comment, and I want to keep this thread updated, but this is both an old question, and already has an accepted answer. I'm always welcome to new members to the StackExchange universe, but you may want to click "help"->"Take a Tour" at the top of the page.

Comment: Thank you so mush for this! I understand, that it actually should be a comment and doesn't provide answer to the question, but it saved my evening. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
val.applyFont(0, val.getString().indexOf("@"), Font.U_SINGLE);
```

You should not pass `Font.U_SINGLE` to `applyFont`,but new a Font, such as `new HSSFFont()`, then `setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE)`.

example:

```
HSSFFont f1 = new HSSFFont();
f1.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
val.applyFont(0, val.getString().indexOf("@"), f1);
```